# Long to Wide restructuring by ID and Days

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given:

```
x <- data.frame(Participant=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
                              "3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"),
                Day= c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
                       "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"),
                verbal=c(1,4,5,6,1,2,8,5,3,4,1,4,5,6,1,2,8,5,3,4,1,4,5,6,1,2,8,5,3,4),
                spatial=c(1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5),
                cognitive=c(5,6,3,5,7,1,2,3,6,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,1,6,7,3,5,7,4,2,5,7,4))
```

Result:

```
y <- data.frame(Participant=c("1","2","3"),
                verbal1=c(1,4,5),
                verbal2=c(1,4,5),
                verbal3=c(1,4,5),
                verbal4=c(1,4,5),
                verbal5=c(1,4,5),
                verbal6=c(1,4,5),
                verbal7=c(1,4,5),
                verbal8=c(1,4,5),
                verbal9=c(1,4,5),
                verbal10=c(1,4,5),
                spatial1=c(1,6,7),
                spatial2=c(1,6,7),
                spatial3=c(1,6,7),
                spatial4=c(1,6,7),
                spatial5=c(1,6,7),
                spatial6=c(1,6,7),
                spatial7=c(1,6,7),
                spatial8=c(1,6,7),
                spatial9=c(1,6,7),
                spatial10=c(1,6,7),
                cognitive1=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive2=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive3=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive4=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive5=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive6=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive7=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive8=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive9=c(5,6,3),
                cognitive10=c(5,6,3))
```

Basically, I'm having trouble restructuring a long format dataset to a wide format. The problem here is that there are multiple variables that need to be called (verbal, spatial and cognitive) so I can't just hit it with a TidyR spread function. The trick here is to break it up into three pieces as found in the comment section:

Solution:

```
x1 <- x %>%
  select(ParticipantID, Day, verbal) %>%
  mutate(Day=paste0('verbal', Day)) %>%
  spread(Day, verbal)


x2 <- x %>%
  select(ParticipantID, Day, spatial) %>%
  mutate(Day=paste0('spatial', Day)) %>%
  spread(Day, spatial)

x3 <- x %>%
  select(ParticipantID, Day, cognitive) %>%
  mutate(Day=paste0('cognitive', Day)) %>%
  spread(Day, cognitive)

final1 <- left_join(x1, x2, by=participant)
final2 <- left_join(x2,final1, by=participant)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to do your job for you. Try to do this yourself and post what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about breaking it up into constituent parts, and then rejoining back together, like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x1 <- select(x, Participant, Day, verbal) %>% mutate(Day = paste0('verbal',Day))
x2 <- select(x, Participant, Day, spatial) %>% mutate(Day = paste0('spatial',Day))
x3 <- select(x, Participant, Day, cognitive) %>% mutate(Day = paste0('cognitive',Day))

final <- left_join(left_join(spread(x1, Day, verbal), spread(x2, Day, spatial), by = 'Participant'), spread(x3, Day, cognitive), by = 'Participant')
final

# Participant verbal1 verbal10 verbal2 verbal3 verbal4 verbal5 verbal6 verbal7 verbal8 verbal9 spatial1 spatial10 spatial2 spatial3 spatial4 spatial5
# 1           1       1        4       4       5       6       1       2       8       5       3        1         5        6        7        3        5
# 2           2       1        4       4       5       6       1       2       8       5       3        1         5        6        7        3        5
# 3           3       1        4       4       5       6       1       2       8       5       3        1         5        6        7        3        5
# spatial6 spatial7 spatial8 spatial9 cognitive1 cognitive10 cognitive2 cognitive3 cognitive4 cognitive5 cognitive6 cognitive7 cognitive8 cognitive9
# 1        1        6        7        3          5           1          6          3          5          7          1          2          3          6
# 2        1        6        7        3          6           1          7          3          5          1          6          7          3          5
# 3        1        6        7        3          6           4          7          3          5          7          4          2          5          7
```

Comment: This works! However, to complicate matters, within my dataset, I have duplicate rows-- where sometimes people have completed a survey twice on a single day, so they have two entries for Day 1. 

To amend my original question :

Day= c("1", "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
                       "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"),

There are two entries on Day 1. When I use your solution, "I get a Duplicate identifiers for rows (41, 42)" error. I'd like to keep the duplicate rows, any idea how to do that?

Comment: There is no way to do that because what you are in essence asking for is to have 2 columns that are both named Verbal1. If only 1 participant has Verbal1, the other participants would get nulls in that column -- is that the desired outcome? If so, I would recommend preprocessing your data whereby if a participant has a duplicate, the second duplicate "Day" is renamed to something like "1a", "1b", etc. and then you'll have columns Verbal1, Verbal1a, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BigTimeStats! 

I borrowed from your technique and split my data based on the duplicated ID numbers then just renamed them beginning 116 and above-- then I cleaned it up and stitched it back together. Thanks for showing me that technique! It's so useful to think in chunks like that.